# Book on the Lambert W function.

Tags: reference-request, taylor-expansion, continued-fractions, lambert-w, reference-works

The [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is the inverse of function $x\mapsto xe^x$. It is traditionally denoted by $W(x)$. The function $W(x)$ is  bivalued in interval $(-\frac{1}{e},0)$. See [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) for more details.

> **QUESTION.** Is there a book with a one chapter or several chapters devoted entirely to Lambert's W function?

By chapters it is "*entirely devoted to Lambert's W function*" I mean chapters containing at least one of the six iteins below:

1. Expansion, in Taylor series, of the W Lambert function around specific points $x_0\in (-\frac{1}{e},\infty)$ with the corresponding radius $r>0$  of convergence.
2. Expansion, continued fractions, of the W Lambert function in specific points $x_0\in (-\frac{1}{e},\infty)$.
3. A table of values $ W (x) $ of Lambert's W function when $ x $ assumes values $ x = 0,1,2,3, \ldots $
4. An iterative procedure or a well-defined algorithm to calculate the values $ W (x) $ to $ x $ belonging to an appropriate subset of $ (-\frac{1}{e},\infty)$.
5. Applications in solution of non linear equations $f(x)=g(x)$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$,
6. Applications in solutions of ordinary differential equations,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any book containing such a chapter, but you might find interesting the article [*On the Lambert $W$ Function*](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf), by several authors (among whom Donald E. Knuth).

Comment: In a quick glance, it seems to me a promising reference. I'll be looking carefully. Thank you so much.+1.

Comment: I hope that you'll find it useful.

Comment: The article is unfortunately not there anymore, so here is an archive of it: http://web.archive.org/web/20190105235042/http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf

Comment: the article is here https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf