# Solving a transcendental equation with complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis

Good day. I want to solve the following equation for $z\in\mathbb{C}$, 
$$e^{\alpha zi}+\beta z+\gamma=0$$
for some constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$.
My question is: is there a way to solve it getting the explicit values of $z$? Is it even possible?
I tried to expand the exponential in its Taylor series but it led me nowhere.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equality is of the form $(a,b,c\ne0)$:
$$ae^x+bx+c=0$$

Let us find the general solution .

First it's equivalent to :
$$\frac{a}{b}e^x+x+\frac{c}{b}=0$$
Or 
$$\frac{a}{b}e^x=-\left(x+\frac{c}{b}\right)$$
Or:
$$\frac{b}{a}e^{-x}\left(-\left(x+\frac{c}{b}\right)\right)=1$$
Or:
$$e^{-x-\frac{c}{b}}\left(-\left(x+\frac{c}{b}\right)\right)=\frac{a}{b}e^{-\frac{c}{b}}$$

Put $u=-x-\frac{c}{b}$ and $v=\frac{a}{b}e^{-\frac{c}{b}}$ wich gets :

$$ue^u=v$$

Now you can solve it using the definition of the Lambert's function

Comment: Thanks! It seems correct to me! I'm accepting this answer. One quick question. I have to admit I didn't know the Lambert's Function. I saw it on Wikipedia, but do you know a book where I can find it in an easy way to understand it?

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2969478/book-on-the-lambert-w-function

Comment: When everything is complex numbers. Is there a way to obtain a series representation of the value of W at that point?,  is it possible to obtain where is the range of W at that point? I am particularly interested in knowing if the solutions of the initial equation could be near the real axis

Answer (score 1):

The general solution can be written in terms of the so-called $W$ function (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), 
$$
 z = \frac{-\beta \,  W\left(\frac{i \alpha  }{\beta} e^{-\frac{i \alpha \gamma }{\beta}} \right)-i \alpha \gamma }{i \alpha \beta } 
$$
but you cannot express $W$ in terms of "elementary functions".

Expanding in Taylor series does not help because it is a very high degree (infinite) polynomial in $z$, which you cannot solve.
Hence, the expansion is quite useless, unless you want to expand for $|\alpha|\approx 0 $ and find an approximate solution. 
For example, the solution up to the second order in $\alpha$ is
$$
z = -\frac{1+\gamma}{\beta} + i \alpha \frac{1+\gamma}{\beta^2}  +O(\alpha^2)
$$
You can easily find the solution up to the third order, but you have to expand the exponential by keeping the term in $\alpha^2$. If you are patient enough you can expand the exponential to the third order as well and solve a cubic equation in $z$...